# Linear model from iterative process in R

Tags: bootstrap, autocorrelation, model, spatial, biostatistics

I would like to test a relationship between to factors such as birds occurrence and temperature for instance, to test if temperature affects birds occurrence from a country (e.g. Germany).

I have a sample of 200 points from Germany taken randomly.

I extract from those points the temperature and birds occurrence values.

I repeat the sampling of 200 random points 100 times, in a way that I compute 100 iterations of a linear model `lm(birds occurrence ~ temperature) -> lm_model`.

I choose to proceed by iteration, as 200 points alone are not representative of the entire country, and as spacial auto-correlation issues will pop-up if I take into account all location points from Germany at once. *Nb: the aim is to process a linear model removing spatial autocorrelation effect without using a Spatial Autoregression error model (SARerr).*

At the end, I have 100 *lm_model* output, with vectors of 100 p-values, 100 slopes and 100 standard errors values. I would like to extract from those:

- one p-value representative of all 100 p-values generated,
- one slope (=estimate) to know if my relationship is positive or negative,
- one standard error.

Example of code (with *birds_list[[i]]* a list with 200 birds occurrence values):

```
for(i in 1:100){
 lm_model <- summary(lm(birds_list[[i]]~ temperature_list[[i]]))
 lm_estimate[[i]] <- lm_model[[4]][2,1]
 lm_std_error[[i]] <- lm_model[[4]][2,2]
 lm_pv[[i]]  <- lm_model[[4]][2,4]
}
```

Concerning the p-value, I used so far the so called 'sum of logarithm' https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/metap/versions/1.0/topics/sumlog which seems fine, but for the slope and standard error, I am not sure how I can do that ... Not sure if taking a mean / median would be correct ...

Does the overall approach seem correct? Does anyone would have a suggestion on a way of generating the slope or standard error values?

Comment: The spatial correlation across samples will make your p values etc. correlated in a very complex way, thus biasing the results of the pooling step. Why avoid standard techniques that deal with spatial dependence?

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I wanted to avoid the use of SAR because I got this kind of results: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1472-4642.2006.00293.x . But maybe I still should use it and acknowledge the limitation/bias of the model in the discussion?... Even though I would like my results to be the most reliable.

Comment: There are other modelling techniques such as mixed effects models with spatial correlation or IML to consider.

Comment: If you want to combine the slopes (or any other estimate) you might consider using meta-analysis with inverse weighting. Since you are using R you might like to look at the packages metafor or meta both of which are available from CRAN.